# Return different types from a single method c# web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that returns a customer object when called. However, if an error happens, i want to return an error string. But, how to return different types in a single method of c#.

```
 public IEnumerable<Customers> getCustomersById(string id){

        var isAuthenticated = tokenAuthorization.validateToken(access_token);
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
            Customers customer = null;
            customer = new Customers();
            customer.kunnr = id;
            customer.name = "John Doe";
            customers.Add(customer);
            return customers;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'Not a valid Access Token';
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code you posted it's in the API Controller than you can do this:

```
public IHttpActionResult getCustomersById(string id){

    var isAuthenticated = tokenAuthorization.validateToken(access_token);
    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
        Customers customer = null;
        customer = new Customers();
        customer.kunnr = id;
        customer.name = "John Doe";
        customers.Add(customer);
        return Ok(customers);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Not a valid Access Token");
    }
}
```

If your code is in a service than you can do the same thing in the controller but throw a custom exception from your service, something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Customers> getCustomersById(string id){

    var isAuthenticated = tokenAuthorization.validateToken(access_token);
    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
        Customers customer = null;
        customer = new Customers();
        customer.kunnr = id;
        customer.name = "John Doe";
        customers.Add(customer);
        return customers;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TokenInvalidException("Not a valid Access Token");
    }
}
```

And then in the controller you can catch that error inside that API call and use the same return type and methods I've showed in the previous example. Or the generic error handler can handle that error as well. Although I would recommend implementing your own error handler filter if you are using custom errors so you won't return 500 errors.

Answer (score 3):

don't return, instead throw.

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well since the "string" your *second message* is due to an **exception** it should be handle as such like:

```
public IEnumerable<Customers> getCustomersById(string id){

        var isAuthenticated = tokenAuthorization.validateToken(access_token);
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
            Customers customer = null;
            customer = new Customers();
            customer.kunnr = id;
            customer.name = "John Doe";
            customers.Add(customer);
            return customers;
        }else
        {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No person with ID = {0}", id)),
            ReasonPhrase = "Person ID Not Found"
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
    }
    return item;
}
```

As you can see the example above you can pass on certain level of information as part of your exception to do the proper handling on client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some generic api response model something like

```
public class ApiResponse<T>{
public T Data {get;set;} // it will contains the response
public string Message {get;set;} // here you can put you error message
public boolean IsSuccess {get;set;} //this will be true only when no error
}
```

and than in your response

```
public ApiResponse<IEnumerable<Customers>> getCustomersById(string id){
var retVal = new ApiResponse<IEnumerable<Customers>>();
var isAuthenticated = tokenAuthorization.validateToken(access_token);
if(!isAuthenticated){
retVal.Message="You are not authrized";
return retVal;
}
try{
var data = yourList;
retVal.IsSuccess = true;
retVal.Data = yourList;
}
catch(exception ex){
retVal.Message=yourmessage;
}
return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer generic solution for this.

```
public class ResponseList<T> {

        public ResponseList() {
            Exceptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public ResposeCodes ResposeCode { get; set; } = ResposeCodes.Success;

        public Dictionary<string, string> Exceptions { get; set; } = null;

        public List<T> DataList { get; set; } = null;

        public string ResponseMessage { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

Here Response code should be look like this:

```
public enum ResposeCodes
    {
        Error = 1,
        Success = 2,
        NoDataFound = 3
    }
```

Response message you can give response like "Your data has been saved successfully."

Here is the good example of how to use this

```
public ResponseList<Model> GetData( string ta_id ) {
            ResponseList<Model> response = new ResponseList<Model>();
            List<Model> res = null;
            try
            {
                res = new List<Model>();
                //perform your operations
                res.data = responselist;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleResponse.AddException(ex, ref response);
            }
            response.DataList = res;
            return response;
        }
```

Here is the handle response class

```
public static class HandleResponse {
        public static void AddException<T>( Exception ex, ref ResponseList<T> response) {
            response.ResposeCode = ResposeCodes.Error;
            response.Exceptions.Add(ResposeCodes.Error.ToString(), ex.Message);


            //inserting errors into table                

        }

        public static void AddErrorMessage<T>( string message, ref ResponseList<T> r ) {
            r.ResposeCode = ResposeCodes.Error;
            r.ResponseMessage = message;
        }

        public static void AddSuccessMessage<T>( string message, ref ResponseList<T> r ) {
            r.ResposeCode = ResposeCodes.Success;
            r.ResponseMessage = message;
        }
    }
```

This should be followed in all apis. We are using this generic solution in our webapi. till now its going very good.